# How to dynamically add style tags to Gutenberg editor in react

Tags: block-editor, react

[image]

Is there any way to add a dynamic style tag to the editor content area by react. The inner content will change by editing. Is any component or hook can use?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need to do exactly, and what exactly is dynamic?